# Mail going to recepient spam folder

Tags: gmail, postmark

We are using Post Mark API for sending mails to recipient for every action performing in our app.We are using VM file as the template for sending mails.Our clients are repeatedly saying that mail was received in spam folder instead of inbox so we surfed online for some reasons related to spam mail.

As per suggestions, we have removed below header from the mail template(vm file)

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

So a sample mail would be like following

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>

<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
 /* Style goes here*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                   <div>
                    Hi $UserName,

                    Thanks for registering.

                    Thanks,
                    Selvam.M
                   </div>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After removing the header we could receive mails directly to inbox other than gmail. But in gmail alone first mail was coming as spam after i have read that all the other mails started to arrive at inbox

May i know what we are doing wrong here?

Comment: Can we get some suggestions on this?

Comment: Anyone could some suggest what's been wrong here???

Answer (score 0):

Have you added DKIM records to your DNS? That's the first thing to do to ensure good delivery. You can also reach out to us at support@postmarkapp.com and we'll be happy to help you further there.